# async/await usage on a code sample

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I am struggling with understanding what is the goal of C# async/await keywords, can you help me by providing code sample, when they are useful?

I have prepared the most simple code piece I can imagine that uses thread to avoid blocking of the method. After researching async/await articles I think this is the case when async/await might become handy. However I encountered some problems which I won't be describing for the sake of question clarity.

So, can the following code be improved by introducing these keywords, and if it can, how?

```
    public void ReturnASAP()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            LongRunningTask(DoneCallback);
        });

        thread.Start();
    }

    private void LongRunningTask(Action doneCallback)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000); //long running operation
        doneCallback();
    }

    private void DoneCallback()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Long running task is done! Huray!");
    }
```

If this isn't the case where async/await are useful, can you provide similarly simple code piece where they are? Please don't bother providing text only description of what they are for, I just gave up trying to understand them without clear and concise code sample.

Thanks!

PS: There are plenty of questions about async/await usage but they do not provide small and simple code piece and seem rather unclear to me, please do not make this question a duplicate.

EDIT:

It turns out that the sample I provided is indeed too simple to reap benefits of async/await. I have come up with another sample myself. Ok, here follows the code that does not use async/await, it needs to execute two sequential tasks in non-blocking manner:

```
    //need to execute LongRunningTask2 after LongRunningTask is finished
    public override void ReturnASAP()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            LongRunningTask(() =>
            {
                DoneCallback(DoneCallback2);
            });
        });

        thread.Start();
    }

    private void LongRunningTask(Action doneCallback)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000); //long running operation
        doneCallback();
    }

    private void LongRunningTask2(Action doneCallback2)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000); //long running operation 2
        doneCallback2();
    }

    private void DoneCallback(Action doneCallback2)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Long running task is done! Huray!");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Starting Long running task 2");

        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            LongRunningTask2(DoneCallback2);
        });

        thread.Start();
    }

    private void DoneCallback2()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Long running task 2 is done! Huray!");
    }
```

Rewritten with async/await it looks much better:

```
    public override async void ReturnASAP()
    {
        await LongRunningTask();

        System.Console.WriteLine("Long running task is done! Huray!");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Starting Long running task 2");

        await LongRunningTask2();

        System.Console.WriteLine("Long running task 2 is done! Huray!");
    }

    private Task LongRunningTask()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000); //long running operation
        });

        thread.Start();
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private Task LongRunningTask2()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000); //long running operation 2
        });

        thread.Start();
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

That's what I needed, thank you guys anyway, your hints helped me to come up with solution. I wish that in one of multiple articles I read on async/await was this short example.

Comment: You are equating `async`/`await` with threading and parallelism, they are not the same.  I suggest you do some bing'ing around for some blog posts and articles about the topic.  This is not, IMHO, a valid question for SO.

Comment: @CodingGorilla I think you mean 'googling'. =)

Comment: you provide a simple enough answer yourself. The goal of the threading would allow the application to still be reponsive whilst 'LongRunningTask' is being executed. async and await are simply promises to return when the task it complete.

Comment: @Jacobr365 No I don't! :P

Comment: Seems like .NET becomes more like Zen with every new version. Cryptic concepts that even cannot be explained by code sample. Feel like I asked what is the sound of one hand clap.

Comment: If you can't get .Net version of the explanation of async/awiat - read JavaScript one https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await - it is exactly the same concept and syntax. It is very hard to help if one already read a lot and none of the articles helped.

Comment: Well, after edit this question looks rather like blog post. If it can be taken from hold I will mark it as an answer though.

Comment: The short/simple answer is that `async` is most useful for I/O. Or - a bit more generally - anytime you want to start an operation, keep the thread free while the operation is in progress, and then take some action when the operation completes.

Answer (score 1):

The async / await version for your code would (arguably) be:

```
public async Task ReturnASAP()
{
    var task = LongRunningTask();   //1

    DoSomeLogic()   //3

    await task; //4

    //Do some more logic here //6
}

private async Task LongRunningTask()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000); //2
    System.Console.WriteLine("Long running task is done! Huray!"); //5
}
```

The numbers represent the order of which the lines are executed. A big difference between this code and yours, is that this code is completely single threaded, and the thread don't get blocked.

> If this isn't the case where async/await are useful, can you provide similarly simple code piece where they are?

Given your comment below, your example is not the case where async / await comes in handy. In your code you spawned a new thread to do some cpu bound work in parallel to the main thread - async / await is all about asynchronous programming, not parallel programming. In my example `LongRunningTask()` is I/O bound, a classic case for async programming.

Comment: If he wants the method `ReturnASAP` to do what it says on the tin, he should just immediately await the `LongRunningTask` - this will return control to the caller, where he can perform extra work, until the Task has completed.

Comment: I agree, but since it was an educational question rather than practical one, I allowed myself to add some extra code to make the idea more clear.

Comment: I saw this sample, it does not explain anything, sorry. I don't have Task.Delay in my long running logic, there is just very long calculation that takes a couple of seconds (that's why I put comment //long running operation)

Comment: @EugeneKr It wasn't clear from your original post that `LongRunningTask` is cpu bound. Read my updated post.